# how to get onclick event of li with a div id

Tags: javascript, yui

if the code snippet is like this:

```
<div id="test">

<div>
<h3>First section</h3>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div>
<h3>Second section</h3>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 6</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

I have the id "test" of the first div. how can i get the `innerhtml` of clicked items. like alert the answer "item 1" when  `<li><a href="http://example.com">Item 1</a></li>` is clicked. I already tried this following code

```
var ul = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
ul.onclick = function(event) {
event = event || window.event;
var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
alert(target.getAttribute("href"));
};
```

This working good only for the first section ul. i need the same to happen for **N** uls. What will be the best method for this. Thanks in advance.

**Note:**  In my project i can't use jquery. only javascript or YUI is supported

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over each `ul` and add the click handler to it like

```js
var uls = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName('ul');
for (var i = 0; i < uls.length; i++) {
  uls[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler)
}

function clickHandler(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  alert(target.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

```html
<div id="test">

  <div>
    <h3>First section</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Second section</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Event Delegation to achieve the expected result.

1. Bind a single event handler to the parent, and get the child from `event.target`

```js
//Get the object of the div#test
var testDiv = document.getElementById('test');

//Bind onclick event for the div#test object
testDiv.onclick = function(e) {
  
  //Prevent the default href action (optional)
  e.preventDefault();
  
  //Check whether the target element is an Anchor tag
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'A') {
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div id="test">

  <div>
    <h3>First section</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Second section</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com">Item 6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```